# Unity C# Button On Panel Not Working Putting Script On The Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sure that I am tangled in my own code so it would be easy I bet to help me out of it I would really appreciate someone throwing me a line.

Can you attached a script to a button and then call a method in that script using that button's onClick in the unity inspector?

Comment: Im not sure if I understand. You want to execute method on button click? If so, just add your script to any game object, drag and drop this object with script associated to "On click" list inside button in your inspector, and select what method you want to execute.

Comment: To answer your question yes you can. I would advise to attach the script to a parent object tough that includes all your buttons and call it eg. ButtonManager. After that is done you should be able to drag your ButtonManager into the Button OnClick in the Unity Inspector and choose the Script attached as well as the public functions of that script.

Comment: Thank you both. I just learned that you pull the entire game object that the script is attached to not just the script. Super embarrassing but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

just so you know, you create a specific 'button' in unity, not a GameObject with a sprite, so that it has a built in unity function where you write a very short piece of code:

```
public void FunctionName()
{
    Do(what_youWant.here)
}
```

and put the script on the actual button, then have a look at the button's components list, and you'll see a place for functions; there you select (from the dropdown) your function from the code.